# Batch file not deleting files when run through application

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that removes all files in a certain directory. This works perfectly fine when I run it maually, but when running it from an application, it does not delete the files.

Batch file code:

```
cd "C:\Users\namehere\Desktop\Test" 
del *.* /q
taskkill /im Presenter.exe
START D:\PresenterInstallFolder\Presenter\Presenter.exe
exit
```

The batch file does fire off, as it loads in my application. As mentioned, when run manually, it works perfectly fine.

I'm using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` to start the batch file

Comment: Any error messages? You should do `del *.* /q >> somelogfile.txt` and check what's inside the file. Try to run your application as administrator. If this helps you have an issue with the access rights.

Comment: `cd` won’t change drive (from `D:` to `C:`, for example) unless you specify `/d` parameter. Isn’t this your problem?

Comment: Yes, better use `del "C:\Users\namehere\Desktop\Test\*.*"` instead of the `cd`. Never do `del *.*` if you're not 100% sure you are in the correct directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While TASKLIST and TASKKILL work, you should be able to do a bit cleaner:

```
del /q "C:\Users\namehere\Desktop\Test\*.*" 
WMIC Path win32_process WHERE "CommandLine Like '%Presenter%'" CALL Terminate
START D:\PresenterInstallFolder\Presenter\Presenter.exe
exit
```

What about the following?

```
del /q "%userprofile%\Desktop\Test\*.*" 
WMIC Path win32_process WHERE "CommandLine Like '%Presenter%'" CALL Terminate
START D:\PresenterInstallFolder\Presenter\Presenter.exe
exit
```

It would also seem to me, you would want to terminate the application first, then delete the files:

```
WMIC Path win32_process WHERE "CommandLine Like '%Presenter%'" CALL Terminate
del /q "%userprofile%\Desktop\Test\*.*" 
START D:\PresenterInstallFolder\Presenter\Presenter.exe
exit
```

You may do well to add a Sleep 1 or 2 seconds to give the process time to stop or start as needed.

Other ways to start a program, you could do the following:

```
WMIC process  CALL Create "Notepad.exe"
```

Or, in your example:

```
wmic process call create "cmd /c start /min D:\PresenterInstallFolder\Presenter\Presenter.exe"
```

if you don't want to start a second instance of CMD:

```
wmic process call create "D:\PresenterInstallFolder\Presenter\Presenter.exe"
```

Then, you should be able to do something like:

CALL C:\Path\YourBatchfile.bat

Hope this helps!